# Can I load multiple 3d models for Aframe (format: gltf)

Tags: html, aframe, webvr, gltf, 3d-model

I'm having trouble trying to load multiple models for my project. I have a black hole model and a galaxy model, both in gltf format, however, the second model is failing to load. IS it just that I can only load a single model? Or am I doing something wrong?

Here is part of my code.

```
<a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="blackhole" src="source1.gltf"></a-asset-item>
        <a-asset-item id="galaxy" src="source2.gltf"></a-asset-item>
</a-assets>


    <a-entity position="0 0 0" scale="0.06 0.06 0.06" animation-mixer gltf-model="#blackhole">
      <a-animation delay="12000" attribute="scale" to="0 0 0" easing="linear" dur="8000"></a-animation>
    </a-entity>
<a-enitiy position="0 0 0" scale="0.01 0.01 0.01" gltf-model="#galaxy"></a-enitiy>
```

Comment: Any console errors ?

Comment: In addition to checking for console errors, also check if your failing model can pass the [glTF Validator](https://github.khronos.org/glTF-Validator/) (or its [offline version](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Validator/releases)).

Comment: Make also sure you are in [latest A-Frame release](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/releases) a-animation has been deprecated. You might be in an old version

Comment: It is definitively possible to load many models. Try galaxy without scaling.